# Static library linked with other libs - LINKER warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, linker, sdl

I'm building SDL2 static library. To use it in my program, I have to link with (static) SDL2.lib, but also with winmm.lib, imm32.lib, version.lib, which I assume are stubs for some Windows DLLs. My main goal is to create such a version of static SDL2, so that my program won't have to be linked with those other 3 .libs. I would like to have all the symbols needed in the static library, so that I have to link the exe only with SDL2.lib. I'm using MS VS2012. I had the idea to use the Librarian when building the static SDL2.lib so I added those other 3 libs to Librarian/Additional Dependencies. That worked like a charm. My exe has to be linked only against SDL2.lib.

But when the .lib was linked, I got warnings:

```
warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library  imm32.lib(IMM32.dll)    SDL2main
warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library  version.lib(VERSION.dll)    SDL2main
```

Now my idea is this: imm32.lib and version.lib do not define any previously undefined (in SDL2.lib) symbols. So they are not needed, because all of the symbols in SDL2.lib can be resolved. So I removed those 2 libs from the Librarian and recompiled SDL2.lib. Now when I'm linking my exe against it, I got some unresolved symbols (possibly from those 2 removed .libs).

Could somebody explain to me the meaning of those warnings? And how to avoid them?

Comment: It is definitely wrong, a static lib should not include *any* SDK libraries.  And certainly not any it doesn't need, like imm32 and version.  They should be linked by whatever project actually uses the lib.  And *might* have a need for them.  But SDL pulls off all kinds of questionable stunts, probably best to ignore it or you'll risk getting confounded by the project documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems those symbols aren't used in SDL2.lib, but are used in your main. That's why you have to link those 3 files with your main, and not take a shortcut.